# How to batch rename Media files on Wordpress to remove Special Chars?

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have recently realised that all of my media files that have special chars (such as ç, á, etc) on their names are not being uploaded to my CDN.

The thing is: I have to find a way to rename all of those files and update that on the database also... and I am a very bad programmer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very attractive solution to the problem would be to [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) the file names. That way, the characters would retain their original meaning (retrievable using [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/urldecode)) but should work with any CDN.

Comment: How can I use it to change my current file names and new ones? I mean, I think I understand, just don't know how to apply it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Beto impossible to tell without seeing some code and what Wordpress plugin you use. Maybe worth asking on `wordpress.stackexchange.com`?